# We have a board $15\times15$. Every square we paint in red, blue or green.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We have a board $15\times15$ divided into 225 unit squares. Every square we paint in red, blue or green. Prove that there always exist two rows with the same number of squares of the same color.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why do you think the pigeonhole principle is relevant?

Comment: If you start with each of the rows having different number of red squares, $0$ to $15$ leaving one of the numbers. What happens then if you go with green next and try to do the same? May be try and do this with smaller grid first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Represent a colouring by as a list of 15 triples: $(R,G,B)$ where $R$ is the number of reds in the row etc. You know that $R=0$ can only appear once in the list. Similarly $R=1$ etc. Now what can you say about the total of each component (ie the sum of the 15 $R$s etc)?

Comment: yes i understand the idea, but i don't understand how to show it

Comment: What don't you understand? Call the triples $(R_1,G_1,B_1),\dots,(R_{15},G_{15},B_{15})$. What is the smallest possible total for $R_1+R_2+\dots+R_{15}$ and why?

Comment: 105? sum from 0 to 14

Comment: @AndreaKamil Great! You have almost done the Q! So what is the minimum sum of three totals? And what do you know the actual sum of the three totals has to be?

Comment: @AndreaKamil $225 \div 3 = 75.$ $\left[\sum_{k=0}^{12} k\right] = 78 > 75.$  Since there are only 225 squares, for at least one of the colors, the total # of squares occupied by that color, in all rows combined, must be $\leq 75.$

Comment: @user2661923 why 12?

Comment: @almagest ok the minimum sum of 3 is then 210, but it has to be 225. I still dont see it:(

Comment: @AndreaKamil Nothing special about the number 12.  Simply that almagest has already indicated that the fewest squares that can be occupied by **each of the three colors** is equal to $\left[\sum_{k=0}^{14} k\right] > \left[\sum_{k=0}^{12} k\right] > 75.$  That is, if you have 3 numbers each of whom is $\geq 105$, then their sum must be greater than $(225)$.

Comment: @user2661923 thanks i got it

Comment: @AndreaKamil $3\times105$ is not 210 !

Comment: @almagest  thnaks now i see it